# Ошибка TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.MultiCellRange'>

Tags: python, openpyxl

Пишу код, чтобы можно было из одной таблицы excel внести некоторые данные в другую таблицу excel.

Все сделал, все проверил, все работает. Но!

Буквально через полчаса еще раз проверяю - и начинает выдавать ошибку

```
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.MultiCellRange'>
```

Притом, что я не вносил абсолютно никаких изменений в код.

Буду крайне признателен всем, кто откликнется!

Вот весь мой код:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

example_1 = 'example_1.xlsx'
example_2 = 'example_2.xlsx'

wb_example_1 = load_workbook(example_1)
wb_example_2 = load_workbook(example_2)

ws_example_1 = wb_example_1['Шаблон для поставщика']
ws_example_2 = wb_example_2['Worksheet']


def item_name(num1, num2):
    num1_1 = int(input('Введи ЧИСЛОВОЙ номер СТАРТОВОЙ ячейки (СТРОКИ): '))

    for a in range(num1, num2 + 1):
        cell_data_example_1 = 'C' + str(a)
        cell_data_example_2 = 'A' + str(num1_1)
        ws_example_1[cell_data_example_1] = ws_example_2[cell_data_example_2].value
        num1_1 += 1
    return ws_example_1


num1 = int(input('Введи ЧИСЛОВОЙ номер СТАРТОВОЙ ячейки (СТРОКИ): '))
num2 = int(input('Введи ЧИСЛОВОЙ номер КОНЕЧНОЙ ячейки (СТРОКИ): '))
item_name(num1, num2)

wb_example_1.save(example_1)

wb_example_1.close()
wb_example_2.close()
```